# Flow layout with centered content

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a row with items which should stack when the window width gets too small for displaying all items in a row, as shown in the following sketch:

[image]

The `Flow` component stacks the items but they are not centered but aligned on the left or right side:

```
Flow {
    Item {}
    Item {}
    Item {}
    Item {}
    Item {}
}
```

Is there a built-in way in QML to make the flow centered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there is no built-in way but I found a workaround to do it.

The idea is simple, since [`Flow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html) is already an [`Item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) it has [`anchors.leftMargin`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors.leftMargin-prop)  and [`anchors.rightMargin`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors.rightMargin-prop). So if we can calculate, how many elements is inside the row of the`Flow` then we are able to calculate the left and right margins. So we can center in.

Here it is a simple code,

```
        Flow {
        property int rowCount: parent.width / (elements.itemAt(0).width + spacing)
        property int rowWidth: rowCount * elements.itemAt(0).width + (rowCount - 1) * spacing
        property int mar: (parent.width - rowWidth) / 2

        anchors {
            fill: parent
            leftMargin: mar
            rightMargin: mar
        }

        spacing: 6
        Repeater {
            id: elements
            model: 5
            Rectangle {
                color: "#aa6666"
                width: 100; height: 100
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another very similar use case is to have the initial, smaller flow horizontally centred as well:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Slider {
        id: slider
        value: 10
        to: 100
        stepSize: 1
        width: parent.width
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    Flow {
        id: flow
        width: Math.min(implicitW, maxW)
        spacing: 4
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        readonly property int columnImplicitWidth: children[0].implicitWidth + spacing
        readonly property int implicitW: Math.max(0, (repeater.count * columnImplicitWidth) - spacing)
        readonly property int maxW: Math.floor(parent.width / columnImplicitWidth) * columnImplicitWidth

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: slider.value
            delegate: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 40
                implicitHeight: 60
                color: "transparent"
                border.color: "darkorange"
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: flow
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "red"
    }
}
```

I think `GridLayout` is even better for this, though, because unlike `Flow`, it doesn't leave the extra space on the right edge:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Slider {
        id: slider
        value: 10
        to: 100
        stepSize: 1
        width: parent.width
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    GridLayout {
        columns: implicitW < parent.width ? -1 : parent.width / columnImplicitWidth
        rowSpacing: 4
        columnSpacing: 4
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        property int columnImplicitWidth: children[0].implicitWidth + columnSpacing
        property int implicitW: repeater.count * columnImplicitWidth

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: slider.value
            delegate: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 40
                implicitHeight: 60
                color: "transparent"
                border.color: "darkorange"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks with `GridLayout`:

[image: gridlayout-gif]

Answer (score 2):

CenterFlow.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle{
    implicitHeight: elements.height
    default property alias content: elements.children
    property int flowSpacing: 0
    color: "transparent"
    Flow{
        function mar(){
            var rowCount = parent.width / (elements.children[0].width + flowSpacing);
            if(rowCount> elements.children.length){
                rowCount = elements.children.length
            }
            rowCount = parseInt(rowCount)
            var rowWidth = rowCount * elements.children[0].width + (rowCount - 1) * flowSpacing
            print(elements.height)
            return (parent.width - rowWidth) / 2

        }
        spacing: flowSpacing
        id:elements
        leftPadding: mar()
        rightPadding: mar()
        width: parent.width
    }
}
```

Use it like this：

```
CenterFlow {
     id:centerFlow
     flowSpacing: 10
     width: parent.width -10*2

     Button{

     }
     Button{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT the, previous answers don't really answer the question. They only seem to center the flow/grid by itself, but not the elements inside. Items will only be centered as long as there's just 1 row. With multiple rows they will just fill the last row from left to right. So here's an approach which always centers items:

```
        Flow {
            id: flow
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            property int columns: 3
            property int cellWidth: width / columns
            property int totalRows: flowRepeater.count / columns

            Repeater {
                id: flowRepeater
                model: 5
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    id: flowDelegate
                    width: Math.floor(flow.width / itemsInRow)
                    height: 100
                    color: "transparent"
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: "red"
                    property int row: Math.floor(index / flow.columns)
                    property int itemsInRow: row < flow.totalRows ? flow.columns : (flowRepeater.count % flow.columns)

                    Rectangle {
                        color: "blue"
                        height: 80
                        width: height
                        radius: width / 2
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built-in way to do so. You have to make your own element.