# Center-align items in QML flow structure

Tags: qt, qml

I want to align items in the following manner:

desired alignment

[image]

I want to have as many items as can fit in one row, and also I want them to be centered. I managed to do the former using Flow QML Type and got this result:

flow alignment

[image]

but it seems that it doesn't have an option to auto center items. Is there anything I missed in Flow documentation or can other type accomplish such alignment?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flow layout with centered content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462117/flow-layout-with-centered-content)